# How detect if the childNode(at specific index) is pressed in accessibilityservice(android)?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, accessibilityservice

As object of currentNode holds reference to our views and layouts, so we can get the childNode(view) from the currentNode. So is there any way to detect if the childNode(at specific index)  is pressed(clicked) in AccessibilityServices.

Or through the event(object reference) is there any way to detect a particular view is clicked(pressed).

```
 @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {

        AccessibilityNodeInfo currentNode = getRootInActiveWindow();

        /// maybe something like this, just for illustration 
        if(currentNode.getChild(0)/*is pressed*/){ 
           // click detected...
        }
}
```

The actions can be performed on the childNode like:-

`currentNode.getChild(0).performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK)`

but instead of this I want to detect if the childNode is pressed(clicked).